# Is there a way to get the mouse to automatically focus on an active window?

Tags: mouse, dual-screen

I have a dual screen setup and its easy enough to switch between active applications but I was wondering if there was a way to bring the mouse over to the other screen.

Comment: how would it know what is the "active" window?

Comment: @Buscar웃, presumably in much the same way that LazyMouse can snap to the default mouse button in a dialog box. It's a matter of iterating through the windows to find which one has focus and then 'snapping' to the new position. That said, I am unaware of any utilities out there that feature such functionality.